# HEX DUMP from OpenCV programs for microcontrollers ? [Image processing]

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, microcontroller, microprocessors

Is it possible to get HEX DUMP from OpenCV programs for microcontrollers/microprocessor ?
Or do you strongly suggest MatLab ?

FOR IMAGE-PROCESSING.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: oh!
I have my algorithm build in C programming language.
Complied in OpenCV environment.
Where i have used OpenCV library functions.
Now i need my program to be dumped into microcontroller.

So is there way to port my program to the assembly code or directly to the hex file which that specific microcontroller can support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before installing OpenCv, 
Set the CMAKE parameter's accroding for that microcontroller/microprocessor.

Ex: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Building_OpenCV_for_ARM_Cortex-A8

Answer (score 1):

Your computer and the microcontroller understand different sets of instructions, so **it's not possible** to simply dump the binary code out of a desktop application and throw it in a microcontroller.

Anyway, if you want to use [OpenCV in a microcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351016/176769) you will need to build OpenCV for that microcontroller through a process known as **cross-compiling**.

Comment: No need to thank, just **up vote** the answer.

Comment: :D
Sure.. vote up the Question also ;-)